# Is it possible to get duplicates in query?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

i'm building user application with backend and i want to know something

datastore query use indexes to retrieve data

if a user have data in this index and in multiple entries of this index 
would the query return him multiple times

say i have a user entity with a list this list is a list of multiple string representing locations like user is in location [A,AB,ABG,ABGJ,ABGJC]

if i query if a user in location A or AB

the query will return the user 2 times ?

cause it will look for all the user in location A then look for all the user in location AB and the same user is in two location A and AB

the user will return 2 times?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Any single entity will only show up once in a query result.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get an Entity once from a query even if it matches mutiple parameters in the query, you can only get multiple result of the same Entity if you run the query differently.

Answer (score 0):

A datastore query will never return the same entity twice.

In your case, if you are modelling a collection with a user and different locations, you have to do multiple entries of the same user with different locations, with the indexing on user and locations. This will allow you to query on it and will return multiple results as there are multiple entries. But if u add an array of locations as a field of a user and you only have one entry per user, you cannot query using a single location even if the array of locations is indexed.

Alternative is to model it in parent and child, and to use ancestor queries.